# Funny behaviour when plotting a polynomial of high degree and large coefficients

Tags: numerics, polynomials, precision-and-accuracy, faq

I am trying to plot a polynomial of degree $29$ on the domain $[0,1]$, with fairly large coefficients:

```
poly[z_] = -1.1126829840302355` + 113.28783661058498` z - 
9878.742379213338` z^2 + 584715.8646149524` z^3 - 
2.280647160113914`*^7 z^4 + 6.176933520283158`*^8 z^5 - 
1.217581378062843`*^10 z^6 + 1.811582263559531`*^11 z^7 - 
2.0920133095023196`*^12 z^8 + 1.9158620445090305`*^13 z^9 - 
1.414955836879161`*^14 z^10 + 8.539129365981781`*^14 z^11 - 
4.254563022912091`*^15 z^12 + 1.764182366816184`*^16 z^13 - 
6.125080435776876`*^16 z^14 + 1.7883504482275766`*^17 z^15 - 
4.403320010637656`*^17 z^16 + 9.154951756734264`*^17 z^17 - 
1.6068672087698447`*^18 z^18 + 2.3765393965161196`*^18 z^19 - 
2.950846281328122`*^18 z^20 + 3.0579497598096415`*^18 z^21 - 
2.6220913470110597`*^18 z^22 + 1.837651151556163`*^18 z^23 - 
1.0344252684666292`*^18 z^24 + 4.5602474296077024`*^17 z^25 - 
1.5155510563521117`*^17 z^26 + 3.568596763872067`*^16 z^27 - 
5.304183668348243`*^15 z^28 + 3.7404713997980006`*^14 z^29
```

The problem is that when I try to plot the polynomial, all seems fine near 0, but then midway through the unit interval I observe some erratic behaviour as shown below. Can anyone tell me why this is and how I can avoid it?

```
Plot[{poly[z]}, {z, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> precision]
```

[image: I would expect the polynomial to be a smooth curve]

Comment: Have you considered that you're working with a 29th degree polynomial with insanely huge coefficients? It's not surprising to me that you get a plot like that. It may seem "nice" early on, but that's because z^29 (and other high-order terms) is very small near 0. Near approximately 0.85, it rapidly approaches 1.

Comment: @Mithc, I will have to disagree with you. Just because the terms of the ploynomial get large as z goes to 1 does not mean you should expect this type of erratic behaviour. Indeed the polynomial can have no more than 29 real roots! So why you expect a plot like this is beyond me. You should not have voted the question down. I suspect a numerical issue here and was hoping somebody could help me pin it down.

Comment: It's cancellation error. Per advice in the response, use higher precision and/or rationalize the coefficients. And be sure you know what you are doing in terms of what might comprise an "expected" outcome, because the result might not mean much if the actual coefficients really have error intervals associated with them.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) your real numbers you will be able to use *Mathematica's* arbitrary precision engine:

```
poly2 = Rationalize[poly[z], 0];

Plot[poly2, {z, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### Arbitrary and machine precision

*Mathematica* has two kinds of numeric calculations: machine precision, and arbitrary precision.  Machine precision is fast but is limited to 53 binary (≈16 decimal) digits<sup>[(1)](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/04/06/anatomy-of-a-floating-point-number/)[(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4947666/618728)</sup> and may lose precision during a calculation.  *Mathematica* also does not track the precision of a result.

Numbers entered as `1.234` or `` 1234` `` are taken to be machine precision.

Arbitrary precision is slower, but *Mathematica* will track the precision of calculations, often using more calculations as necessary to preserve precision, and print the precision of the result.

Exact values such as `1234` and `1/2` can be used in arbitrary precision calculations.  Numbers can also be entered with e.g. `` 1.234`20 `` specifying 20 digits of precision, and these will automatically use arbitrary precision if *all other values* are either exact or arbitrary.

Precision can be checked with the function `Precision`:

```
Precision /@ {1.234, 1234`, 1.234`20, 7}
```

> ```
> {MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision, 20., ∞ }
> ```

Precision can only be preserved if all values in a calculation have at least that precision.  Also, arbitrary precision arithmetic may be used with numbers having a precision less than [`MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MachinePrecision.html) -- *Mathematica* will show the true precision of the result.

```
Precision[1.234 + 7]

Precision[1.234`20 + 1.234`12]
```

> ```
> MachinePrecision
>
> 12.301
> ```

Precision can be set with [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html).  It is probably better to use this rather than `Rationalize` to put numbers into a form that the arbitrary precision engine will use, because the latter will be manufacturing false precision.

Applying this to your problem:

```
poly3 = SetPrecision[poly[z], 15];

Plot[Evaluate[poly3], {z, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

> During evaluation of In[91]:= Plot::precw: The precision of the
>   argument function <<>> is less than WorkingPrecision (50.`). >>

This is an important warning because it lets you know that your results may not be valid.

See [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html) for more information about precision.  Take time to understand the difference between *Mathematica's* meanings of [`Accuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy.html) and [`Precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html).

---

Recommended reading, a more recent answer from Szabolcs regarding arbitrary precision:

- [Very different results from evaluating same expression with different precisions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32782/very-different-results-from-evaluating-same-expression-with-different-precisions/32869#32869)

---

### [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html)

Michael's answer shows the folly of simply doing a `Rationalize` as I did at the start of this answer.  Since questions like this come up often it would be good to have a general solution that is easily applied.  I propose this rule using his formula:

```
machineToInterval = 
  c_Real?MachineNumberQ :> 
    Interval[ {1 - 2^-54, 1 + 2^-54} SetPrecision[c, ∞] ];
```

This converts any machine numbers into explicit [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html) form.

To extract an ordered pair of values from a numeric `Interval` we merely need `First`.

```
poly3 = poly[z] /. machineToInterval;

Plot[{First @ poly3, poly[z]}, {z, 0, 1}
 , WorkingPrecision -> 50
 , PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, ColorData[97][1]}
]
```

[image]

Comment: @Wizard, Thank you. If possible can you give me some insight into the problem and the solution.

Comment: @aukie see the updated answer

Comment: To complement this, calculating the polynomial value in Horner form (`HornerForm`) increases precision somewhat, but not enough.

Comment: @Szabolcs But strangely enough including `WorkingPrecision->20` does allow `HornerForm` to work: `Plot[HornerForm[poly[z]] // Evaluate, {z, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 20] // Quiet`.

Answer (score 32):

Here is another way to look at the OP's plot, which came to me after reading [Daniel Lichtblau's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) comment under the question.  His comment is worth emphasizing, which I think the following will show. ([Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) alludes to the issue in his remark on validity near the end of his answer.)

Let's say that machine precision is [binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), which has 53 bits of precision, and the maximum relative rounding error is `2^-53`.  Let's be a little fuzzy and say that the average error is roughly half that or `2^-54`.  The we can get almost exactly the envelope of the OP's plot as follows.  We can replace the coefficients with ones that are slightly larger and smaller (according with the relative `error`); since `z >= 0`, the two resulting polynomials form estimates for the upper and lower bounds on `poly[z]`.  (I'll use a high working precision,  as in [Mr.Wizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) answer, to compute the bounds precisely.)

Let's show two sets of bounds: `bounds` is in accordance with the average relative error and will form the envelope of the OP's plot; and `absbounds` is in accordance with the maximum relative error.

```
boundsPlot[error_, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] := With[{
    polyMin = poly[z] /. c_Real :> (1 - Sign[c] error) SetPrecision[c, Infinity],
    polyMax = poly[z] /. c_Real :> (1 + Sign[c] error) SetPrecision[c, Infinity]},
   Plot[{polyMin, polyMax}, {z, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, opts]
   ];
bounds = boundsPlot[2^-54, PlotStyle -> {Darker@Blue, Darker@Green}, PlotRange -> 5];
absbounds = boundsPlot[2^-53, PlotRange -> 5];

plotOP = Plot[poly[z], {z, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[0.7], Red}, PlotRange -> 5];

Show[plotOP, absbounds, bounds]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A good way to think of floating-point numbers is that they represent an **interval** of real numbers.  At best a floating-point number is an approximation obtained by rounding the true value in an interval to the binary representative.  An average error of `2^-54` is about as precise as the coefficients could be if they are thought of as random variables uniformly distributed throughout each interval.  The `bounds` above show the range of likely possible values of `poly[z]`, although occasionally `poly[z]` exceeds `bounds`.

The upshot is this:   ***Under the hypothesis that the coefficients are known to `MachinePrecision`***, *the OP's original plot more accurately represents what is known about `poly[z]`, than the better-looking high-precision plot.*  The plot `bounds` seems to show the likely limits of the plot of the polynomial, under the same hypothesis (although calculating the probability is beyond me).  Similarly, the plot `absbounds` shows absolute bounds on the `poly[z]`.  Under the hypothesis, using `absbounds` or `bounds` seems the appropriate way to represent `poly[z]`.

If the error is greater than `2^-53`, say, because the coefficients are calculated from scientific measurements with less precision, then one can compute the corresponding bounds.

Comment: Great analysis. +1

Comment: I forgot that I needed to apply the variation to the mantissa.  Correcting that I get a result that matches yours.

Comment: Actually it doesn't quite, and I have a guess why.

Comment: I am using `r_Real :> (Interval[Rationalize[#, 0] + {-1, 1} 2^-54] 10^#2 & @@ MantissaExponent[r])`.  Is this more or less accurate than your method?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ah, I see.  I missed that. `SetPrecision` directly converts the binary representation of a machine real into a rational number with an appropriate `2^n` denominator.   `Rationalize` replaces `c` by the rational number with the smallest denominator within roughly `c * $MachineEpsilon` of `c` (e.g. SetPrecision[1./3, Infinity]` vs. `Rationalize[1./3, 0]`).  `SetPrecision` accurately corresponds to the process I described in my answer.  `Rationalize` does something different but close; I don't think that it is the function to use in this analysis.

Comment: Michael, I just added my take on your method to my answer, with credit of course.  I think it provides an easily applied and general form.

Answer (score 14):

Surprisingly enough, [converting the polynomial to the Bernstein basis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84243) yields a result that `Plot[]` can stably deal with:

```
pbconv[poly_, x_] /; PolynomialQ[poly, x] := Module[{bc, n},
                  n = Exponent[poly, x];
                  bc = CoefficientList[poly, x]/Binomial[n, Range[0, n]];
                  Do[bc[[j + 1]] += bc[[j]], {k, n, 1, -1}, {j, k, n}];
                  bc]

pb[z_] = With[{n = Exponent[poly[z], z]}, 
              N[pbconv[SetPrecision[poly[z], ∞], z]] .
              BernsteinBasis[n, Range[0, n], z]]
```

(The cheating with `SetPrecision[]` is necessary because, as mentioned in the answer I linked to, the conversion procedure is inherently ill-conditioned.)

A plot:

```
Plot[pb[z], {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image: look how smooth it got]

This suggests that whatever process that generated the original polynomial  might have been better reformulated in the Bernstein basis.

Answer (score 2):

Settled complain about my post being "off topic".
(My post got complaints about not using a special language thats too expensive for me to buy:"this is a Wolfram Language, not a mathematics, site". I did not pay attention to the brand name in the domain name. I removed the offending post for the reader's benefit.)

Here is @fischertranscripts's idea in Mathematica code (from @MichaelE2), which idea is to center the expansion at the center of the interval to reduce catastrophic cancellation:

```
p4 = SetPrecision[poly[z], Infinity] /. z -> y + 4/10 // Expand // N
(*
1.036149520209514` + 2.6409755026207726` y - 
 0.26953631057648186` y^2 + 3.449324571015004` y^3 + 
 338.0294181630971` y^4 - 11.745703101835632` y^5 - 
 43728.76625187574` y^6 - 8023.6344953736` y^7 + 
 2.8981359277591794`*^6 y^8 + 319591.7190295984` y^9 - 
 1.1561838608969387`*^8 y^10 + 1.6950583018096235`*^7 y^11 + 
 2.9997779821296453`*^9 y^12 - 1.5058103605142357`*^9 y^13 - 
 5.259500639613633`*^10 y^14 + 4.791402548859846`*^10 y^15 + 
 6.297914684319244`*^11 y^16 - 8.57877729466455`*^11 y^17 - 
 5.062935150456753`*^12 y^18 + 9.554822737249043`*^12 y^19 + 
 2.5656319594205586`*^13 y^20 - 6.75013786580717`*^13 y^21 - 
 6.66863314102059`*^13 y^22 + 2.924066304682213`*^14 y^23 - 
 1.0628093808994717`*^13 y^24 - 6.905409809370671`*^14 y^25 + 
 5.294845683864764`*^14 y^26 + 5.772127663081625`*^14 y^27 - 
 9.652368445825622`*^14 y^28 + 3.7404713997980006`*^14 (y^29) 
*)

Plot[p4, {y, -0.4, 0.6}, AxesOrigin -> {-0.4, 0}, 
 Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks[{# - 0.4 &, # + 0.4 &}], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps, you could plot the curve for your transformed polynomial.

Comment: And show the expansion that gave that particular set of coefficients.

Comment: Hard to beat `Plot[Evaluate@{poly[z]}, {z, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> precision]`, for "easy", if you're starting from `Plot[{poly[z]}, {z, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> precision]` (assuming precision is >20). As this is a Wolfram Language, not a mathematics, site, it would be better to post your solution in WL code. For instance, `p4 = SetPrecision[poly[z], Infinity] /. z -> y + 4/10 // Expand // N; Plot[p4, {y, -0.4, 0.6}]`, which takes 0.159 sec. compared to 0.0167 sec for `precision = 20`.

Comment: It was a pretty good idea though, and it happened to work pretty well. But for someone who does not know or have the tools you used, it's a lot harder than using Mathematica to accomplish the equivalent thing. -- Roll back my edit if you'd rather your answer be deleted.

Comment: @fischertranscripts What I meant by "happened" is that the coefficients after the transformation happened to have negligible cancellation error. I think your transformation will reduce it, but does it always make it negligible?

Comment: This method, as coded, assumes the coefficients are exactly known. If they are off by as much as an ULP then things can and will change. Try for example `pc0 = CoefficientList[SetPrecision[poly[z], Infinity], z];
Show[Table[
  pc1 = pc0 + 
    Map[RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]*#/RandomInteger[{10^16, 10^17}] &, 
     pc0];
  poly5 = 
   Expand[FromDigits[Reverse@pc1, z]] /. z -> y + 4/10 // Expand // 
    N;
  Plot[poly5, {y, -0.4, 0.6}, AxesOrigin -> {-0.4, 0}, {30}]]`