# Failed to use SetPrecision

Tags: summation, arbitrary-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I am calculating the below formula:
$$
\text{ER2}(\alpha,\text{K},\text{q})\text{:=}1+\sum _{m=0}^{K-1} \binom{K+\alpha }{m} \sum _{r=0}^m \frac{(-1)^r \binom{m}{r}}{\left(\frac{1}{q}\right)^{\alpha +K-m+r}-1};
$$
with the code:

```
ER2[α_, K_, q_] := 1 + Sum[Binomial[α + K, m] 
     Sum[Binomial[m, 
        r]*(-1)^r /((1/q)^(α + K + r - m) - 1), {r, 0, m}]
    , {m, 0, K - 1}];
```

when $\alpha=0,K=268,q=0.1$. The code produced a negative number -7306.51.
But I know the answer is positive! And Maple produce 3.196969869 as expected.
I think it's the matter of [cancellation error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3152/funny-behaviour-when-plotting-a-polynomial-of-high-degree-and-large-coefficients), so I tried to use SetPrecision:

```
ER2PP = SetPrecision[ER2[α, K, q], 50];
```

Mathematica complaints:

```
NSum::nslim: Limit of summation -1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000+K is not a number.

NSum::nslim: Limit of summation -1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000+K is not a number.

NSum::nslim: Limit of summation -1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000+K is not a number.

General::stop: Further output of NSum::nslim will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Please help me to solve the problem, thanks!

Comment: Try `ER2[0, 268, 1/10] // N`.

Comment: The error is due to the real number 0.1. I tried <code>ER2[0, 268, 0.1`40] // N</code>, and it also produce an positive number. But I still can't understand why it's failed to use SetPrecision...

Comment: Sorry for the code format. I mean the code is `ER2[0, 268, 0.1\`40] // N`.

Comment: `SetPrecision[exp,p]`, according to the documentation, "yields a version of expr in which all numbers have been set to have precision p."  Thus, it probably changes integer indices to real numbers, which may cause problems.  What I find curious is that including `SetPrecision` inside the definition of ER2, either around the outer `Sum` or the inner `Sum`, produces no error messages but also computes the wrong answer to high precision.

Comment: I noticed that the precision of ER2 itself is infinity. When substitute q with 0.1, the precision decreased. And maybe that's impossible to SetPrecision like such a summation due to the inner algorithms used by Mathematica. @bbgodfrey

Answer (score 4):

The only `InexactNumberQ` is $q=0.1$ so you have two options:

1. replace it with `1/10` i.e. with `Rationalize[0.1]` i.e. `SetPrecision[0.1, Infinity]` if you want an exact answer and compute with exact numbers; you can later use `N` to get an approximation of the exact anser;
2. replace it with `SetPrecision[0.1, 50]` i.e. *0.1`50* if you want to do the computation with 50 digits arbitrary precision numbers.

There is no need to use `SetPrecision` on the whole expression and this can cause problems with other exact number (for example a side effect of using inexact numbers as bounds in `Sum` is that `NSum` is used actually).

There is also a problem in your expression `SetPrecision[ER2[...], 50]` because `SetPrecision` act once ER2 has already computed the (wrong) result, i.e. `SetPrecision` is not `HoldFirst`. You can use `Unevaluated`.

```
Clear[ER2]
ER2[α_, K_, q_] := 
  1 + Sum[Binomial[α + K, m] Sum[
      Binomial[m, r]*(-1)^r/((1/q)^(α + K + r - m) - 1), {r, 0,
        m}], {m, 0, K - 1}];
ER2[0, 268, 1/10] // N
ER2[0, 268, SetPrecision[0.1, 50]]
SetPrecision[Unevaluated@ER2[0, 268, 0.1], 50]
```

> ```
> 3.19697
> 3.196969869247707935345524749
> 3.1969698692477079353455247
> ```

As you can see, placing `SetPrecision` in the right place pay off also in terms of precision of the result.

Answer (score 0):

On 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014) and with the settings

```
α = 0; K = 268; q = 1/10;
```

all works fine:

```
ER2PP = SetPrecision[ER2[α, K, q], 50]
```

> 3.1969698692477078742102832950849543981411237482710

```
ER2[0, 268, 1/10] // Short
```

$\frac{133756473090706713\langle\langle 21765\rangle\rangle 656008497136924720}{418385153946357022\langle\langle 21764\rangle\rangle 593232363264815721}$

```
N[%]
```

> 3.19697