# Issues with ConvexOptimization and SetPrecision

Tags: mathematical-optimization, precision-and-accuracy, arbitrary-precision

I am completely new to Mathematica (second day), so do not expect things to look polished.

I am trying to perform a [ConvexOptimization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexOptimization.html) over a List/Array (dimensionality `e-2`)with custom (higher) precision. The plain version works just fine:

```
e=4;

PepGamma[z_, combinedA_] := 1 + z + z^2/2 + Sum[combinedA[[i]] * z^(i + 2), {i, e - 2}];
combinedA = Array[gam, e - 2];
Print[PepGamma[z, combinedA]];

omega = -1;
deltaT = 0.5;
ConvexOptimization[Abs[PepGamma[omega * deltaT, combinedA]] - 1, {}, combinedA]
```

Now if I want to specify a certain precision of the objective `PepGamma`, similar as done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72179/failed-to-use-setprecision)

```
PepGammaPrec[z_, combinedA_] := SetPrecision[PepGamma[z, combinedA], 10];
Print[PepGammaPrec[z, combinedA]];
```

this seems to work.
But then calling the optimizer

```
ConvexOptimization[
Abs[PepGammaPrec[omega * deltaT, combinedA] - 1], {}, combinedA, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```

gives first the (strange) message

> ConvexOptimization::precw: The precision (9.778151250383644`) of the objective and constraints is less than the specified WorkingPrecision 10.`.

Alright, then lets try this with a smaller `WorkingPrecision`, say `9`. But then the optimizer reports:

> ConvexOptimization::nnobj: The objective does not evaluate to a real numerical value since the value of ObjectiveConstant is Abs[-0.3750000000-0.1250000000 gam[1.000000000]+0.06250000000 gam[2.000000000]].

How can this be? I also tried this with very small (`2`and very high precision `50`), in both cases the optimizing routine reports that it is not able to find a solution, although the default case finds one.

Comment: It seems calling `SetPrecision`, also changes indices precision, `gam[2.000000000]` instead of `gam[2]`. `Indexed` seems to solve the problem. Just change the `combinedA` definition to `Array[Indexed[gam, #] &, e - 2]`.

Comment: Thanks! That indeed seemed to have solved it. I was also worried about this, but when I checked the element access with e.g. `combinedA[1.000000]` it seemed to work. But probably not within the optimization package. Anyways, thanks again!