# Funny behavior when computing dot product of coefficients with high-order polynomials

Tags: numerics, polynomials, precision-and-accuracy

I have a similar problem to [Funny behaviour when plotting a polynomial of high degree and large coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3152/funny-behaviour-when-plotting-a-polynomial-of-high-degree-and-large-coefficients). However, the thing being evaluated is not just a polynomial, but a dot product of some coefficients with a list of polynomials.

(The back story is that I want to distort a sine random variable so that it has an approximate Laplace distribution. I am doing this by approximating the nonlinear mapping with a Chebyshev approximation. This has the cool property that if I use a `maxN`-th order Chebyshev series then there are only `maxN` harmonics of the sine wave. If the exact mapping is used, there are an infinite number of harmonics.)

The dot product (coefficients times Chebyshev polynomials) begins to become inaccurate (blow up, oscillate like crazy, whatever) near $\pm 1$ for `maxN` greater than the mid-$40$s. I've tried the `Rationalize` function on the coefficients--the polynomial coefficients are all integers--but to no avail.

Here is what I've tried. I have included the exact mapping for comparison to the Chebyshev approximation. (Mathematica told me that this involves the `SinIntegral` so I have hard-coded that into the definition.) The mapping has odd symmetry about the origin so even-order coefficients are zero.

```
FLaplaceInverse[x_, β_] := 
  Piecewise[{{β Log[2 x], x < 1/2}, {-β Log[2 - 2 x], 
     x >= 1/2}}];
FSine[x_, b_] := (π + 2 ArcSin[x/b])/(2 π);
CompositeSineLaplace[x_] := FLaplaceInverse[FSine[x, 1], 1];
maxN = 49;
chebCoeffList = 
  Table[If[EvenQ[n], 0, 
    N[(4 SinIntegral[(n π)/2])/(n π), 100]], {n, 0, maxN}];
rChebCoeffList = Rationalize[chebCoeffList, 0];
chebPolyList = 
  Table[If[EvenQ[n], 0, ChebyshevT[n, x]], {n, 0, maxN}];
plotBoth = 
  Plot[{CompositeSineLaplace[x], 
    rChebCoeffList.chebPolyList} , {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> Automatic,
    ImageSize -> Medium];
plotDiff = 
  Plot[Evaluate[
    CompositeSineLaplace[x] - chebCoeffList.chebPolyList] , {x, -1, 
    1}, PlotRange -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Medium];
chebCoeffsWithOrder = 
  Transpose[{Table[n - 1, {n, Length[chebCoeffList]}], chebCoeffList}];
plotCoeffs = 
  ListPlot[chebCoeffsWithOrder, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium];
{plotBoth, plotDiff, plotCoeffs}
```

The `Plot` functions give this for `maxN = 49`.

[image: Chebyshev approx and target function, difference, and the Chebyshev coefficients]

Comment: It is nice to use the Chebyshev polynomial expansion fo this purpose. However, you are in effect converting back to the ill-conditioned monomial basis here. Why not use Clenshaw? Also, you are wasting effort by not exploiting the oddness of your function; there are identities that only require you to retain the odd terms.

Comment: For the time being: try cranking up `WorkingPrecision`.

Comment: Numerical Recipes as well as GNU Scientific Library incorporate Clenshaw's method; I have been using the Numerical Recipes code for a while until I noticed something weird. The NR guys say, compute more Chebyshev coefficients than you need, say M, then just truncate to how many you want, say N < M. The assumption is that the truncated terms will cause a negligible error. However, I found that if I compute M1 then M2 terms and then truncate each time to N terms, the N terms are different for the two cases. I attribute this either to slow convergence to -+infinity at ±1 or my coding error to Ada

Comment: Hmm… if I find time later I might investigate this (unless somebody beats me to it). Re: NR, they gave the identities for evaluating an odd Chebyshev series efficiently IIRC. Use them!

Comment: By suggesting that I increase `WorkingPrecision` I gather that you mean, add it to the Plot statement. I don't think this will help—anyway, I tried with value of 100 with no change in the plots.

Comment: Ah, then you have a severe case of precision loss going on; did you try implementing Clenshaw summation already?

Comment: Please ignore the comment above by me beginning, "By suggesting...." I hit Return to start a new paragraph and accidentally posted a messed-up comment. (I don't know why I initially didn't see any improvement.)

Comment: I increased `WorkingPrecision` in the Plot statements to 30+ and indeed the `Plot` evaluation is OK. Thanks.

Instructive (to me) are the following two statements:

`ListPlot[Table[rChebCoeffList.chebPolyList, {x, -1, 1, 1/1000}]]`
`ListPlot[Table[rChebCoeffList.chebPolyList, {x, -1, 1, 0.001}]]`

The first works fine and is slow while the second is fast but blows up for large maxN. So I guess the problem I posted is solved in principle but I don't know how to control the `Plot` statement to get symbolic evaluations like in the first `ListPlot` statement above. Adding `Evaluate` does nothing.

Comment: By the way, using `Rationalize` had no obvious effect on either the `Plot` results or the `ListPlot` results; only increasing `WorkingPrecision` helped for `Plot`, and symbolic evaluation for `ListPlot`. But note that `chebCoeffList` are being evaluated to 100 digits. Also, this works:

`ListPlot[Table[
  SetPrecision[rChebCoeffList.chebPolyList, 50], {x, -1, 1, 
   SetPrecision[0.001, 50]}]]`

Comment: "`Rationalize` had no obvious effect on either the `Plot` results" - that would be on account of `Plot[]` doing all its evaluations in machine precision unless specifically told not to (through `WorkingPrecision`).

Answer (score 5):

To resolve this:

Compare

```
Plot[chebCoeffList.chebPolyList, {x, -1, 1}]
```

with

```
Plot[chebCoeffList.Table[If[EvenQ[n], 0, ChebyshevT[n, x]], {n, 0, maxN}],
     {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: spot the difference]

The blowup seen in the first plot is, as noted, due to the fact that `chebPolyList` is already converted automatically to the monomial basis, which is terribly ill-conditioned for numerical evaluations of this sort. In contrast, the evaluation in the second one did not involve this conversion; that is, `ChebyshevT[]` was directly evaluated at the inexact numbers fed to it by `Plot[]`. Setting `WorkingPrecision` to a higher value in the first plot can stave off this ill-conditioning, but at the expense of increased effort.

---

As also noted in the comments, a more efficient way of proceeding would be to use the [Clenshaw recurrence](http://dlmf.nist.gov/3.11#Px3) to evaluate your Chebyshev series. This has to be modified a bit to exploit the oddness of your function. Thus,

```
cheboddval[c_?VectorQ, x_] := 
           Module[{n = Length[c], u, v, w, y = 4 x^2 - 2}, 
                  u = c[[n - 1]] + y (v = c[[n]]);
                  Do[w = v; v = u; u = c[[k]] + y v - w, {k, n - 2, 2, -1}];
                  x (c[[1]] + (y - 1) u - v)]
```

Let's generate your coefficients without the zeroes taking up space:

```
cc = Table[N[(4 SinIntegral[n π/2])/(n π), 50], {n, 1, maxN, 2}];
```

Now, the plot:

```
Plot[{CompositeSineLaplace[x], cheboddval[cc, x]}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: only the tiny wiggles distinguish the two]