# How to force Mathematica to plot the log function correctly for the given argument?

Tags: plotting, approximation

Consider functions

```
logargument[p_, q_, mp_] = 
  (-mp^2 - p q + Sqrt[mp^2 + p^2] Sqrt[mp^2 + q^2])/(-mp^2 + p q +
       Sqrt[mp^2 + p^2] Sqrt[mp^2 + q^2]);

Qp[mS_, p_, mp_] = 
  1/(2*mp^2)*
   Sqrt[2*p^2*mS^4 - 2*p*mS^4*Sqrt[p^2 + mp^2] - 4*mp^2*p^2*mS^2 + 
     4*mp^2*p*Sqrt[p^2 + mp^2]*mS^2 + 4*p^2*mp^4 + mp^2*mS^4 - 
     4*mS^2*mp^4];
```

I have a problem when trying to plot the function `Log[logargument[p,Qp[mS,p,mp],mp]]` for small mS. Namely, the plot

```
Plot[{Log[logargument[10, Qp[mS, 10, 1], 1]]}, {mS, 10^-4, 10^-3}]
```

doesn't show the behavior correctly, since for such small mS the function returns Indeterminate. This is due to asymptotic behavior of the `logargument` function for large `p` and very small `mS` (and for `mp` in between), which is 
$$
\tag 1 \frac{m_{S}^{4}m_{p}^{2}}{64p^{6}}
$$ 
This can be shown by using the code

```
qpapprox[p_, mS_] = 
 Assuming[p > 0 && mp > 0, 
  Normal@Series[Normal@Series[Qp[mS, p, mp], {mp, 0, 4}], {mS, 0, 4}]];
logargumentapprox[p_, mS_, mp_] =FullSimplify[
 Assuming[mS^2 - 4 p^2 < 0 && p > 0, 
  Normal@Series[
    Normal@Series[
      logargument[p, qpapprox[p, mS], mp], {mp, 0, 2}], {mS, 0, 4}]]]
```

My questions are the following. How to force Mathematica to plot the logarithm of `logargument` function correctly? The problem is that this logarithm enters another very complicated function of arguments `p,mp,mS` which I need to plot for arbitrary `mS` including large ones, for which the problem disappears, and I thus can't simply replace the function `logargument` by its approximation $(1)$.

Comment: Try `LogPlot[{logargument[10, Qp[mS, 10, 1], 1]}, {mS, 10^-4, 10^-3}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]`. Related: [3152](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3152/funny-behaviour-when-plotting-a-polynomial-of-high-degree-and-large-coefficients)