# Is there anyway to remove the noise from the graph in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to find the root of an equation in Mathematica. But am unable to find it. The Plot function gives a very noisy graph. Can anyone please provide me with a solution to this

```
    A10=

-0.24999999999999997` (2.611333478147288`*^17 \
(-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + (8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
        7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.` + 
   2.611333478147288`*^17 (9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
        7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.`) \
(-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + (8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
     7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5` (9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
     7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5` (-5.3376918284751424`*^26 \
(-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + (8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
        7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.5` Cosh[
     204404.83274706744` (9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`] Sin[
     204404.83274706744` (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
          7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`] Sinh[
     183964.3494723607` (9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`]^2 + 
   Sinh[204404.83274706744` (9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
          7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`] \
(2.6688459142375712`*^26 (9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.5` (Cos[
          163523.86619765396` (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`] - 
         Cos[204404.83274706744` (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`]) + 
      5.222666956294576`*^17 (2.611333478147288`*^17 \
(-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + (8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
              7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.` + 
         2.611333478147288`*^17 (9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
              7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.`) (-0.000072` + 
         5.2226669562945766`*^13 (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
              7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.` \
(9.305307031664072`*^-8 + (8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 

              7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.`) \
(-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + (8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
           7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5` \
(9.305307031664072`*^-8 + (8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
           7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5` Sin[
        204404.83274706744` (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`] + 
      2.6688459142375712`*^26 (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.5` Sin[
        204404.83274706744` (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
             7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`] Sinh[
        367928.6989447214` (9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`]))

    Plot[A10, {P, 0, 10}]
```

[image: The plot]

Is there any way to improve the accuracy of the plot.

Comment: Retry after `Remove[A10, P]`, I can't reproduce it in V11.3

Comment: I couldnt get you...could you please be a bit more specific about Remove [A10,P]

Comment: @Coolwater is saying: "Evaluate `Remove[A10, P]`, then try to evaluate your code again" (`Remove` clears any definitions that might still float around from earlier)

Comment: There is no other definition. I need to plot the equation A10 so as to find the smallest root arising from this equation. But with this present plot, it is impossible to detect the smallest root

Comment: It works fine in *Mathematica* 10.4.  Nice smooth plot with zeros at 0 and around 5.75.

Comment: I have been using Mathematica 11.0. It gives a very noisy plot. Ill check out in 10.4

Comment: Versions 11.0.0 and 11.0.1 on my Mac produce smooth plots.

Comment: Ive edited the equation. The equation was rounded one when i copied but if the equation is not rounded off.. Then the equation gives the following noisy curve

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3152/funny-behaviour-when-plotting-a-polynomial-of-high-degree-and-large-coefficients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

A10 = -0.24999999999999997` (2.611333478147288`*^17 (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 \
+ (8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.` + 
     2.611333478147288`*^17 (9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
            7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.`) (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
         7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5` (9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
         7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5` (-5.3376918284751424`*^26 \
(-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + (8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
            7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.5` Cosh[
       204404.83274706744` (9.305307031664072`*^-8 + (8.658873895353684`*^-15 \
+ 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`] Sin[
       204404.83274706744` (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`] Sinh[
        183964.3494723607` (9.305307031664072`*^-8 + (8.658873895353684`*^-15 \
+ 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`]^2 + 
     Sinh[204404.83274706744` (9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
              7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`] (2.6688459142375712`*^26 \
(9.305307031664072`*^-8 + (8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
               7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.5` (Cos[
            163523.86619765396` (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`] - 
           Cos[204404.83274706744` (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`]) + 
        5.222666956294576`*^17 (2.611333478147288`*^17 \
(-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + (8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
                  7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.` + 
           2.611333478147288`*^17 (9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
                  7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.`) (-0.000072` + 
           5.2226669562945766`*^13 (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
                  7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.` \
(9.305307031664072`*^-8 + (8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 

                  7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.`) \
(-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + (8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 
               7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5` (9.305307031664072`*^-8 \
+ (8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5` Sin[
          204404.83274706744` (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`] + 
        2.6688459142375712`*^26 (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^1.5` Sin[
          204404.83274706744` (-9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`] Sinh[
          367928.6989447214` (9.305307031664072`*^-8 + \
(8.658873895353684`*^-15 + 7.658922220148525`*^-18 P)^0.5`)^0.5`]));
```

`Rationalize` and `Simplify` the expression

```
A10r = A10 // Rationalize[#, 0] & // Simplify;
```

Use high precision in the `Plot`

```
Plot[A10r, {P, 0, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 70]
```

[image]

Use `FindRoot` with high precision; however, precision is reduced for display of results.

```
(FindRoot[A10r, {P, #}, WorkingPrecision -> 70] & /@ {10^-10, 58/10}) // N

(* {{P -> -8.4392*10^-14}, {P -> 5.78585}} *)
```