# Getting negative value instead of a positive value

Tags: numerical-integration

The function is
`-((28359.7 (25.64 -8. Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3]) (-145751.-42339.7 Cos[0.666667 \[Phi]]))/(6.35447*10^9+1.09431*10^10 Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3]+0.8 (1.36789*10^10+4.88831*10^8 Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3]) Cos[0.666667 \[Phi]]))`.
I found this function is singular at `\[Phi]` = 2.80043. Then I try to integrate it numerically by excluding `\[Phi]` = 2.80043. The code is as follows.
`NIntegrate[R, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Method -> "PrincipalValue",  Exclusions -> {2.8}]`

I am getting a negative value, which is not true. i should get the value around 20. Please someone look into this, where I have done mistake.

Comment: `NIntegrate[R, {\[Phi],0,2 Pi},Method->"PrincipalValue",Exclusions->{2.80046}]` returns `33.707` but I wouldn't trust any of this with constants like 6.35447*10^9, 1.09431*10^10, 1.36789*10^10, 4.88831*10^8 in your denominator.

Comment: Replacing the two `Cos[0.666667 \[Phi]]` with `Cos[2 \[Phi]/3]` like your other three `Cos` expressions and then doing `FullSimplify` on that whole expression returns a result with far smaller constants. Giving that to `NIntegrate[R,{\[Phi],0,2 Pi},Method->"PrincipalValue",Exclusions->{2.80046}]` returns 2.3526. See how fragile and badly conditioned your problem is? No one can know what the accurate result should be.

Comment: Yes Bill, that's the concern. This evening even i had got 33.707, but then i again ran the program with same code, but i got negative.

Comment: Using `Rationalize` can give you 20 or even 50 digit numbers as exact fractions, But that is just replacing one badly conditioned problem with another, neither one of which will give an answer which means anything. If you need an answer that you can depend on then I would suggest you go back and carefully derive a well conditioned problem before trying to give anything to Mathematica.

Comment: @Bill: Can you ground you claim " But that is just replacing one badly conditioned problem"?

Comment: @user64494 `Rationalize` effectively assumes all decimal approximations are infinitely precise. But decimal approximations are almost never infinitely precise. For example, take every subset of coefficients in his problem and increase or decrease or leave alone each by a factor of 10^-7 and then perform the integration, or even just very carefully plot all those different integrands and see how large a band of uncertainty there is.  Unfortunately `NIntegrate` isn't telling him that the integral is zero+/-30 because of uncertainty in the decimal approximations. If it did that then he would know

Comment: @user64494 And do the same 10^-7 factor changes with your 100 digit rationals and see that the results will be the same.

Comment: You wrote "I am getting a negative value, which is not true. i should get the value around 20." but no details for this claim. Why do you think you know what the value should be?

Comment: Its actually a resistance value in the electric current. So obviously the resistance is not negative. That's why i told it should be positive.By the way, it is not necessary for the value to be 20. It can be any positive value. But it should be a positive value.

Answer (score 1):

Let us switch to rationals by

```
R = Rationalize[-((28359.7 (25.64 - 8. Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3]) (-145751. - 
      42339.7 Cos[0.666667 \[Phi]]))/(6.35447*10^9 + 
    1.09431*10^10 Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3] + 
    0.8 (1.36789*10^10 + 4.88831*10^8 Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3]) Cos[
      0.666667 \[Phi]])) - ((28359.7 (25.64 - 
     8. Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3]) (-145751. - 
     42339.7 Cos[0.666667 \[Phi]]))/(6.35447*10^9 + 
   1.09431*10^10 Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3] + 
   0.8 (1.36789*10^10 + 4.88831*10^8 Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3]) Cos[
     0.666667 \[Phi]])), 10^-6];
```

Now we find the singularity

```
Reduce[Denominator[%] == 0 && \[Phi] >= 0 && \[Phi] <=  2*Pi, \[Phi], Reals]
```

> `\[Phi] ==  3/2 ArcCos[((-11474682511359999 + Sqrt[ 128936041852524956596599521280001])/410061163724800)`

and verify whether the principal value exists:

```
Normal[Series[R, {\[Phi], 3/2 ArcCos[(-11474682511359999 + Sqrt[
 128936041852524956596599521280001])/410061163724800], 1}]]
```

> `(283597 (-\ 8150874560502974171386525279586377768479544128931229678029921919909621\ 7882393287690779 +  7177980461245791809133043915542851489143779773506255352808120017\ 909221 Sqrt[ 128936041852524956596599521280001]))/(\ 1890838028244348811742170217604725064930000 Sqrt[ 128936041852524956596599521280001] \ (-43406038405173438824145660586667 +  3824894170453333 Sqrt[ 128936041852524956596599521280001])) + (283597 \ (-12788928541097983 + Sqrt[ 128936041852524956596599521280001]) (-4260677904521756248603 +  423397 Sqrt[ 128936041852524956596599521280001]) \ \[Sqrt](3/(257872083705049913193199042560002 \ (-43406038405173438824145660586667 +  3824894170453333 Sqrt[ 128936041852524956596599521280001]))))/(9776620000 \ (\[Phi] -  3/2 ArcCos[(-11474682511359999 + Sqrt[ 128936041852524956596599521280001])/ 410061163724800])) + (283597 \ (-14155375205447098928680471998526538311923178615746222212518203042223\ 03228798422400804127604557075641388359898840791914277845526702933 +  1246620367110647775006547791183469130900148171581433830671783967\ 60849011665904411755292709563971603283924005230417067 Sqrt[ 128936041852524956596599521280001]) (\[Phi] -  3/2 ArcCos[(-11474682511359999 + Sqrt[ 128936041852524956596599521280001])/ 410061163724800]))/(\ 157569835687029067645180851467060422077500 Sqrt[ 773616251115149739579597127680006] \ (-43406038405173438824145660586667 +  3824894170453333 Sqrt[128936041852524956596599521280001])^(5/2))`

The  above long output confirms it. In principal,

```
Integrate[R, {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

should work, but its execution is spinning on my comp. Because of this reason, let us switch to numeric integration by

```
NIntegrate[R, {\[Phi], 0, 
3/2 ArcCos[(-11474682511359999 + Sqrt[128936041852524956596599521280001])/410061163724800], 2*Pi}, Method -> PrincipalValue]
```

> `-31.6315`

The result is a negative number despite your claim.
To be sure, let us verify it by the definition of the principal value

```
NIntegrate[ R, {\[Phi], 0, 
3/2 ArcCos[(-11474682511359999 + Sqrt[128936041852524956596599521280001])/410061163724800] - 0.01}] +
  NIntegrate[ R, {\[Phi],  3/2 ArcCos[(-11474682511359999 + Sqrt[
   128936041852524956596599521280001])/410061163724800] + 0.01,  2*Pi}]
```

> `-31.603`

Addition. Working only with the original function,

```
NSolve[Denominator[-((28359.7 (25.64 - 
       8. Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3]) (-145751. - 
       42339.7 Cos[0.666667 \[Phi]]))/(6.35447*10^9 + 
     1.09431*10^10 Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3] + 
     0.8 (1.36789*10^10 + 4.88831*10^8 Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3]) Cos[
       0.666667 \[Phi]]))] == 0 && \[Phi] >= 0 && \[Phi] <=  2*Pi, \[Phi], Reals]
```

> `{{\[Phi] -> 2.80046}}`

, we obtain

```
NIntegrate[-((28359.7 (25.64 - 8. Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3]) (-145751. - 
    42339.7 Cos[0.666667 \[Phi]]))/(6.35447*10^9 + 
  1.09431*10^10 Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3] + 
  0.8 (1.36789*10^10 + 4.88831*10^8 Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3]) Cos[
    0.666667 \[Phi]])), {\[Phi], 0, 2.800455227678918`, 2*Pi}, Method -> PrincipalValue]
```

> `-15.8158`

without any warnings/errors. As we see, `Rationalize` somewhat changes the result quantitatively, but not qualitatively.
PS. It should be noticed that

```
N[3/2 ArcCos[(-11474682511359999 + 
  Sqrt[128936041852524956596599521280001])/410061163724800]]
```

> `2.80046`

Comment: I'd like to add that replacing `R` by `-((28359.7 (25.64 -8. Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3]) (-145751.-42339.7 Cos[0.666667 \[Phi]]))/(6.35447*10^9+1.09431*10^10 Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3]+0.8 (1.36789*10^10+4.88831*10^8 Cos[(2 \[Phi])/3]) Cos[0.666667 \[Phi]]))` in the latest command, we also obtain a negative number.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268501/getting-a-wrong-plot-after-nintegration

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268501/getting-a-wrong-plot-after-nintegration.    This was my yesterday's question. In that long expression i have simply used R = 0.8. please click this link and suggest me what to do.

Comment: @sachirajmishra: Sorry,  I answered that was asked, not another additional question about a plot  you linked. The plot of the function under consideratio is produced by `Plot[R, {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}]`.

Comment: I get `-15.8158` whether or not I rationalize the integrand.  I think that you have an extra factor of precisely two in your answer using rationalized numbers.  Otherwise, a good answer.